# c++ array can't get the right array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have Array `A[9]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and I need to delete the numbers which are not dividing by 2. The code I tried to do:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    ifstream fd(Cdf);
    fd>>n; // read how many numbers are in the file.
    int A[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fd >> A[i]; //read the numbers from file
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) // moving the numbers.
    {
        if(A[i] % 2 !=0)
        {
            for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                A[i] = A[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
    fd.close();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get numbers like `224466888`. what I need to do to get 2,4,6,8?

I need to delete numbers in the same array.

Comment: First comment: meaningful variable names make code easier to read.

Comment: Why not use a better data structure, like `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Comment: @crashmstr Because of learning.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, and learning use of good data structures is a good idea.

Comment: @crashmstr Yes it is, but that's not the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: @molbdnilo but nowhere does it say (at least in the question) what the purpose this is or that there are any restrictions. Thus the general recommendation should be to do things the C++ way, prefer `std::string` over C strings, `std::vector` etc. over arrays.

Comment: Bad assignment.  Values cannot be *removed* from an array.  They can be overwritten.  To verify this, get your program working and look at the last values.  You will need to maintain a separate variable indicating the quantity of valid variables in the array.  Print only the valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your removal loop is indexing with the wrong variable:

```
for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
{
    A[i] = A[i+1];
}
```

You're using `i`, which doesn't change in the loop.
Change it to `j`. You also need to subtract one from the upper limit, as you'd step outside of the array otherwise when accessing `A[j + 1]`.

```
for(int j = i; j < n - 1; j++)
{
    A[j] = A[j + 1];
}
```

Comment: this does still not remove anything

Answer (score 2):

First you should use std::vector for dynamic size arrays.
Second, for removing numbers that are even in a vector, you can do :

```
std::vector<int> inf = {12,0,5,6,8};
auto func = [](int i){return i % 2 != 0;}; 
inf.erase(std::remove_if(inf.begin(),inf.end(),func), inf.end());
```

EDIT :

Ok, so you can still do this without std::vectors, but it will be uglier :

```
#include <algorithm>

int res[] = {2,5,9,8,6,7};
int size = 6;
auto func = [](int i){return i % 2 != 0;};
int new_size = std::remove_if(res,res + size, func) - res;
```

All the data you want is in [0, new_size[ range, the other part of your array is now garbage.

Comment: i can't use the Vector. because i learning it at school. and my teacher give me to do this with the arrays...

Comment: @user3609104 Edited for an array version

Comment: #include <algorithm> // for std::remove_if

Comment: -1 because this answer is useless for a beginner. The exercise is obviously about exploring the basics of arrays and loops, not about using the higher-level parts of the standard library.

Comment: That's one way of seeing it. I personally think that beginner should be aware of portable and robust solution offered by the Standard library, instead of always (badly?) reinventing the wheel, especially on a website that lots of beginners could see for guidance. But i understand your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

An array can't be used for your purpose. It is allocated on stack and its size can't be changed dynamically (you can't change the size of an array in general, not only when it is allocated on stack).

You could allocate a second array and keep reallocating it with `realloc` everytime you add a new element but that's not the good way to do it. You are working with C++ so just use a `std::vector<int>` and your problems will be solved:

```
std::vector<int> evenArray;
evenArray.reserve(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])/2);

if (number is even) {
  evenArray.pushBack(number);
}
```

Mind that vector stores elements contiguously so this is legal:

```
int *evenA = &evenArray[0];
```

Comment: i can't use the Vector. because i learning it at school. and my teacher give me to do this with the arrays..

Answer (score 0):

For your inner `for` loop you should be referencing `j`, not `i`.

```
for(int j = i; j < n - 1; j++)
{
    A[j] = A[j+1];
}
```

Otherwise, what's the point of creating `j`?

Of course, this also means if you read the whole array back you will display all the characters that were shifted (which will just be equal to the last number). So, you should probably keep track of the new length of the array and just iterate to that instead of the end of the array.

EDIT:
In the inner `for` loop you need to loop to `n - 1` otherwise when you have `A[j + 1]` it will go off the end of the array when you to change it, which may or may not give you a runtime error.

Comment: so you say i just need to A[i] = A[i+1] write in the If sentence without For loop?

Comment: No, you need to change the inner `for` loop to use `j` instead of `i` when accessing the array. Otherwise you are just using the value of `i`, which hasn't changed. So, every time you hit an odd number all you're doing is replacing it with the number directly after it. Changing it to `j` and not `i` will make it so it will repeat that process down the array. Though, molbdnilo had a point and you need to make it `n - 1` so you don't go off the end.